# Function returns <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I'm trying to write a function that will return a data frame with two columns (the Date column, and a column of my choice), and one row (which has the max value in specified column of a data frame), to show me which date had the max value.

```
is_max <- function (month, col) {
    sub_row <- which.max(month$col)      #the row index of the max value
    A <- which(names(month) == col)      #the index of the desired column
    y <- month[sub_row, c(1, A)]
    return(y)
}
```

The result should be

```
     Date TOTAL
15 11-Aug    26
```

Instead, this gives the output

```
[1] Date  TOTAL
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

When I work out each line of the function outside of the function body with the month and col data I want it works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not really enough information given, but try it with `month[[col]]` instead of `month$col`, assuming you are passing a character string to the `col` argument. `month$col` is likely returning `NULL` due to no column named `col`.

Comment: I would say there is no column defined as "col", to programmatically to refer to a column try: `which.max(month[[col]])`

Comment: Both answers are correct, it was the indexing method that needed correction. Thank you!